# jQuery Mobile navigation glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

When I am at the home page and use the nav bar at the top to go to page2 and then come back to home. The nav bar glitches out and I'm not sure why. How can I fix this?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3d1oyx2v/15/

**HTML :**

```
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Home</h1>
 <a href="#bars" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="homeContent">
        <p>Home.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="bars" data-theme="a">
        <!-- panel content goes here -->
        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a>

            </li>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Page 2</h1>
 <a href="#bars" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 2.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="bars" data-theme="b">
        <!-- panel content goes here -->
        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Tee Times</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have a repeated id (`#bars` for both menus), and that results in trouble.

Fix the issue by changing the id's so they are unique (e.g.: `#bars1` for the home page and `#bars2` for the page 2), and also the icon links reference accordingly, then it will work fine ([see it on this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d1oyx2v/16/))

```
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Home</h1>
        <a href="#bars1" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="homeContent">
        <p>Home.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="bars1" data-theme="a">
        <!-- panel content goes here -->
        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a>

            </li>
        </div>
        <!-- /panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Page 2</h1>
            <a href="#bars2" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>

        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Page 2.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>

        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->
        <div data-role="panel" id="bars2" data-theme="b">
            <!-- panel content goes here -->
            <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
                <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Tee Times</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
```